# Get different timezones when writing and reading row with datetime column?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-datetime

**Why I get different timezones when writing and reading row with datetime column?**

I have next table `Tests`:

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    test_datetime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __init__(self, test_datetime):
        self.test_datetime = test_datetime

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Test(id={self.id}, test_datetime={self.test_datetime})'
```

I decided to store the aware datetime in utc in the database and Tests table.
I am performing adding a new row to a table. The test object has aware datetime.

```
session.add(Test(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)))
session.commit()
session.close()
```

psql select command output:

```
database_name=# select * from tests;                                                                                                                      id                  |        test_datetime
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------
 751bcef0-2ef4-4c0f-960c-a40ca2b8ec94 | 2021-04-12 14:46:30.8957+03
(1 row)

database_name=# SHOW timezone ;
   TimeZone
---------------
 Europe/Moscow
(1 row)

database_name=# \d tests
                           Table "public.tests"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id            | uuid                     |           | not null |
 test_datetime | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "tests_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

We see the datatime column is incorrectly written to the database (timezone offset +3 hour to place +0).

Reading data from the database, as expected, I get a different timezone (+3h)

```
query = session.query(Test)
for test in query.order_by(Test.test_datetime.asc()).all():
    print(test.test_datetime, test.test_datetime.tzinfo)
```

Python output:

```
2021-04-12 14:46:30.895700+03:00 psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)
```

My database has a TimeZone: "Europe/Moscow".
There is an assumption: it is possible that when writing to the database, the datetime is saved as naive. And all objects in the test_datetime column get the timezone (offset) from the database.
But I'm not sure if it works like that.

Comment: In psql when you do `\d tests` does it show the test_datetime column as "timestamp with time zone"?

Comment: Yes "timestamp with time zone". Added \d output to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL stores `timestamp with time zone` values as UTC and by default displays them in the local time zone. So, if I insert a UTC value via psql …

```
mydb=# insert into tests (id, test_datetime) values (1, '2021-04-12 11:46:30.8957+00');
INSERT 0 1
```

… and then retrieve it …

```
mydb=# select * from tests;
 id |        test_datetime        
----+-----------------------------
  1 | 2021-04-12 05:46:30.8957-06
(1 row)
```

… it is displayed in my local time zone (currently UTC-6). psycopg2 also returns the value in the local time zone

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(
        sa.text("SELECT test_datetime FROM tests WHERE id=1")
    ).scalar()
    print(type(result))  # <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    print(result)  # 2021-04-12 05:46:30.895700-06:00
```

If you want the timezone-aware `datetime` value to be in UTC then just convert it

```py
    result_utc = result.astimezone(timezone.utc)
    print(result_utc)  # 2021-04-12 11:46:30.895700+00:00
```

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter when recording datetime is aware or naive. The value will be saved in the database as UTC. Then, when reading, I will get the offset the value in the local time zone. However, I don't understand the difference between the `timestamp with time zone` and the `timestamp without time zone` - I should always convert the `astimezone()` value when reading.

Comment: The difference between `timestamp with time zone` and `timestamp without time zone` becomes more apparent when you consider more than one time zone. If I was to save `'2021-04-12 12:00:00'` in both columns then "ts_with" would be considered `2021-04-12 12:00:00-06` and would be saved as `2021-04-12 18:00:00+00`. For me, "ts_with" would be `2021-04-12 12:00:00-06` and "ts_without" would be `2021-04-12 12:00:00`. For you, "ts_with" would be `2021-04-12 21:00:00+03` but "ts_without" would still be `2021-04-12 12:00:00` (the same as for me).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the column (with_tz or without_tz) does not store information about the time zone. This property only affects the display of information, for example, when executing a query in the psql console?

Comment: That is correct. `timestamp with time zone` converts the date/time value to UTC and stores it, but it does not store the timezone from which the value was converted (if any). Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30785635/2144390).